# How can I get CURL to correctly perform an HTTP/2 request?

Tags: php, http, curl, https, http2

So I am trying to query the following URL: http://mil.sagepub.com/content/17/2/227.short

Here's the situation: On a browser such as Chrome or Safari it will:

1. 307 to https://mil.sagepub.com/content/17/2/227.short and then
2. 301 to
   https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/03058298880170020901
3. which returns 200

On cURL, it will:

1. 307 to https://mil.sagepub.com/content/17/2/227.short
2. which returns 503

So naturally, I go to Chrome and copy the request to https://mil.sagepub.com/content/17/2/227.short as a bash cURL command.  I paste it into bash, and I get a 503.  I try copying the Safari request to the same page as a bash cURL command, and also a 503.  So seemingly two cURL requests formatted to perfectly imitate the browser request returns a 503.

On my PHP cURL options, I try and experiment with different options, but it also only returns a 503. So I have 3 different OSs and PHP's cURL library getting 503 responses, while web browsers get a 200 OK response.

Here is the outgoing request my PHP code tried to send with cURL:

```
GET /content/17/2/227.short HTTP/2
Host: mil.sagepub.com
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
authority: mil.sagepub.com
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
cache-control: max-age=0
connection: keep-alive
keep-alive: 300
accept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
dnt: 1
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
```

The method that sets all of the curl options and generates the above request header is as below:

```
$url = "https://mil.sagepub.com/content/17/2/227.short"
$full = true
$tor = false
$httpVersion = CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 // HTTP/1.1 doesn't seem to work in this page
$this->userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
$this->curlTimeoutFull = 60
```

```
protected function getCurlOptions( $url, $full = false, $tor = false, $httpVersion = CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE ) {
        $requestType = $this->getRequestType( $url );
        if ( $requestType == "MMS" ) {
            $url = str_ireplace( "mms://", "rtsp://", $url );
        }
        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $this->curlTimeoutNoBody,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => sys_get_temp_dir() . "checkifdead.cookies.dat",
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => $httpVersion,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => 1
        ];
        if ( $requestType == "RTSP" || $requestType == "MMS" ) {
            $header = [];
            $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->mediaAgent;
        } else {
            // Properly handle HTTP version
            // Emulate a web browser request but make it accept more than a web browser
            if ( in_array( $httpVersion, [CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE] ) ) {
                $header = [
                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart Line exceeds 100 characters
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
                    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
                    'Connection: keep-alive',
                    'Keep-Alive: 300',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8',
                    'Pragma: '
                ];
            } elseif ( in_array( $httpVersion, [CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS] ) ) {
                $parsedURL = $this->parseURL( $url );
                $header = [
                    'authority: ' . $parsedURL['host'],
                    //':method: get',
                    //':path: ' . $parsedURL['path'],
                    //':scheme: ' . strtolower( $parsedURL['scheme'] ),
                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart Line exceeds 100 characters
                    'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                    'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                    'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
                    'cache-control: max-age=0',
                    'connection: keep-alive',
                    'keep-alive: 300',
                    'accept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8',
                    'dnt: 1'
                ];
                if ( $requestType == "HTTPS" ) {
                    $header[] = 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"';
                    $header[] = 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0';
                    $header[] = 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "' . $this->getRequestPlatform() . '"';
                    $header[] = 'sec-fetch-dest: document';
                    $header[] = 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate';
                    $header[] = 'sec-fetch-site: none';
                    $header[] = 'sec-fetch-user: ?1';
                }
            }
            if ( $this->customUserAgent === false ) {
                $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->userAgent;
            } else {
                $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->customUserAgent;
            }
        }
        if ( $requestType == 'FTP' ) {
            $options[CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT] = 1;
            $options[CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV] = 1;
            $options[CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH] = CURLFTPAUTH_DEFAULT;
            $options[CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD] = CURLFTPMETHOD_SINGLECWD;
            if ( $full ) {
                // Set CURLOPT_USERPWD for anonymous FTP login
                $options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = "anonymous:anonymous@domain.com";
            }
        }
        if ( $full ) {
            // Extend timeout since we are requesting the full body
            $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = $this->curlTimeoutFull;
            $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $header;
            if ( $requestType != "MMS" && $requestType != "RTSP" ) {
                $options[CURLOPT_ENCODING] = 'gzip, deflate, br';
            }
            $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->userAgent;
        } else {
            $options[CURLOPT_NOBODY] = 1;
        }
        if ( $tor && self::$torEnabled ) {
            $options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = self::$socks5Host . ":" . self::$socks5Port;
            $options[CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE] = CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME;
            $options[CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL] = true;
        } else {
            $options[CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE] = CURLPROXY_HTTP;
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

My question is, what am I missing here?

Comment: Those sites are most likely setting a cookie that's checked on the final page. It may be worth looking at the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option and using it to see if that helps.

Comment: I am supporting cookies for that very reason, but in this particular case, this is not the reason. :-(

Comment: What's missing?  Your PHP curl code.  That is where your error is.  If I cannot see it, I cannot help you.

Comment: @Misunderstood it's happening in Bash too.  It's not just PHP.  Copy the curl request for that URL from a browser and paste it into bash.  You will get the same error.

Comment: Nonetheless, I have added the method that defines all of the CURL options to the question above.  The returned value gets passed directly into the curl handle through curl_setopt_array.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this appears to be CloudFlare using TLS fingerprinting to distinguish cURL requests from actual browsers.  There doesn't likely exist a means to work around this.  Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I have never run into this problem.  But if I did I would try a User Agent that they are unlikely to have a profile.    This is one UA that I would use:  `"User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";`  This is one of the first Motorola phones with Internet capability.  It is a real UA.  You may be wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Last night I had not time to look at the HTML.  Now that I have, it's disappointing. I've taken a little more time to look at the HTML. It is the HTML for the Cloudflare "Checking Security" message.

I retrieved the response header. And it is a 503 response.
I do not have security certificates for my curl and don't really have the time do install the now.

This one is going to be a challenge.  I wish I had more time now because I like a challenge. I may work on this in the near future (weeks/months).

If you are going to continue you may need some of these curl options.

Start with `CURLOPT_CAINFO / CURLOPT_CAPATH`

```
CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT
CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH the HTTP authentication method(s) to use.
CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES
CURLINFO_CERTINFO true to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers
CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME

CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT -
CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL
CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL
Options
CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default
CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS
CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD
CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY
CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE 
CURLOPT_CAPATH A directory that holds multiple CA certificates
CURLOPT_CAINFO The name of a file holding one or more certificates to verify the peer with. 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST 0 to not check the names. 1 should not be used. 2 to verify that a Common Name field 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  false to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS  true to verify the certificate's status. 
CURLOPT_CERTINFO true to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers. 
CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   true to force the use of a new connection instead of a cached one. 
CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN
CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN
CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART  true to enable TLS false start 
CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES
CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST
CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD
CURLOPT_SSLKEY
CURLOPT_SSLENGINE
CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD
CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST
CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE
```

These are the SSL security error codes.

```
CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_NOTFOUND (53)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED (54)
CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM (58)
CURLE_SSL_CIPHER (59)
CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_INITFAILED (66)
CURLE_LOGIN_DENIED (67)
CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE (77)
CURLE_SSH (79)
CURLE_SSL_CRL_BADFILE (82)
CURLE_SSL_ISSUER_ERROR (83)
CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH (90)
CURLE_SSL_INVALIDCERTSTATUS (91)
CURLE_AUTH_ERROR (94)
CURLE_SSL_CLIENTCERT (98)
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/2 503 
date: Fri, 07 Oct 2022 23:36:20 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
referer-policy: same-origin
cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
permissions-policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
set-cookie: __cf_bm=ephtbgHn7LX95.n_3NjMptBv8PFRRJP_6xtBw_9Ci0A-1665185780-0-ATjw+AOJfmTzUGIfBhlg8p6scov6AoznbSauiS3ofTN6KYEebpn4p+k3lU+5l6zZRwENm0kYDHa9zptcfePujs8=; path=/; expires=Sat, 08-Oct-22 00:06:20 GMT; domain=.sagepub.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 756a755a18e95e68-TPA
```

---

End of Update

---

I tried the curl below and it appeared to work.
When I used this header it did not work.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; UTF-8");
```

Notice the header() below.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain; UTF-8");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/03058298880170020901');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0',
    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'DNT' => '1',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest' => 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode' => 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site' => 'cross-site',
    'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=aaaf4hNAtZPHz_3k0KSoy; SERVER=lZreQKWihabND4/rEplMDWnYKk2egCfX; __cf_bm=PzjJU2qBrjwilfLqClzWC.zRk49hsY6b7e4F8WtMiMA-1665105299-0-AYf2x4A2SmmdyIQGUHAY0jdkGZtI3qyt3W48WENOL6tGZLEYJ/IqcD5GAWn10V5J+khYliOD7yhKrtVlGXwpawI=; MAID=cqVoyumi6JY4MYyiVyj//w==; MACHINE_LAST_SEEN=2022-10-06T18%3A15%3A00.400-07%3A00; usprivacy=1Y--');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

**This is the response**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">

</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">
            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico"
                 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)" />
            journals.sagepub.com
        </h1>
        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=7562d7b24c405e68')"></div>
        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">
            journals.sagepub.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>
        <form id="challenge-form" action="/doi/abs/10.1177/03058298880170020901?__cf_chl_f_tk=2isUlGhlWW3V2j9Kjj8DwMFDI2e5zBKVHQMe3nobTys-1665105922-0-gaNycGzNCOU" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="PQaRto6SpdNW5tB2CzRq9tnhClVf9vWYghzKuRjDWOQ-1665105922-0-AeraO7jbF6VbQcW0RvUhPT1qfbCcUTYiREg7FWQynA4OVtiTbls-NlCSXpbPLK_-bVRyI6_Wphk1k1XY_lxg0MVXMZ2tT5RmeYGnJYD5T-de61VfREEcZtpE5oaFnFmWVY38q9TYjq1CllDiszTadCdO-j4yvW51pLjc-LT8Z4OIHRgA1TG92oykPVkBoKgUcuUVGpZhsklb5S7Mz5h31OlmT8X_oMpHigkNwFWCVnuxl5_6FePRATc-hGFOYs6YFMu6P2GlAOigwfjRBmYi1ftmoQqBXK7wmb9HHmzrz1_BurTIQMFZyL-GExcvzgMud539jGN1mhQMiEfA44cezwbDBCp_TZLvF0l4_jx6ON49_M1aKzD3uM0Y7AO7WY7RnoED4ljPYcBvOQJyIF0QY_LLCZPoApA2pP4ku8J3uHa1ziS_fL6vOJD-cEkHMKMEFWMoOYCNYVQg1z_x0k7Pj2O_7svXqMyqk990LloFkmezlHPnw7k58EE8A8-KZavGjKAZnVKI4nZ5Kgr1ng8IDwsk64EiblwOTmvQoGBDObBxNI5QKmHY1of7zyaSlv233SzrJpn1JMP8o1gqtIVkQKTsV5cz8RQ59Zdrfc30zJhtc0R4REKiX7KaQ6hfmoZQLkuocj_TIF1cFYcF_UD_sl1gqV4pKejaZXtYc-zScMFCQBBPlgRIN3z2QD47WFCBR8-AQWgq2mkxE8GvbfwgoBw" />
            <input type="hidden" name="r" value="4ga_OQoCt0ZP_Qytdr9ME00oPYmCHboqWnNiiVPIL4o-1665105922-0-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"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cType: 'non-interactive',
            cNounce: '61335',
            cRay: '7562d7b24c405e68',
            cHash: '10218f759e4ab19',
            cUPMDTk: "\/doi\/abs\/10.1177\/03058298880170020901?__cf_chl_tk=2isUlGhlWW3V2j9Kjj8DwMFDI2e5zBKVHQMe3nobTys-1665105922-0-gaNycGzNCOU",
            cFPWv: 'b',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cTplV: 4,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9qb3VybmFscy5zYWdlcHViLmNvbS9kb2kvYWJzLzEwLjExNzcvMDMwNTgyOTg4ODAxNzAwMjA5MDE=',
                ra: '',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY2NTEwNTkyMi45NDIwMDA=',
                m: 'uhMFR0Zz2KvO1IklAUNSaC4Dp7dCmCc5//+PPZeITRY=',
                i1: '00a08NzJ+5CkmeYGE9ULuA==',
                i2: '05tMwHIIyy7WJUV2JWbeXA==',
                zh: 'gw7YMdbZ1M4iQ6cbqLPC730Ml6kaQ+3i4OTRjaElasU=',
                uh: 'DV4j3Tmrbi5Rs1q3ahwVS6SgbPbI7np5884QO1u1Cgg=',
                hh: 'c9ogzZPyf3xtUVOiYSAQbEsbym/d5b1rPQM2Rm/OUTE=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/js/transparent.gif?ray=7562d7b24c405e68');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=7562d7b24c405e68';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/doi\/abs\/10.1177\/03058298880170020901?__cf_chl_rt_tk=2isUlGhlWW3V2j9Kjj8DwMFDI2e5zBKVHQMe3nobTys-1665105922-0-gaNycGzNCOU" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>

    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">
                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>7562d7b24c405e68</code></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=j" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Using `header("Content-Type: text/html; UTF-8");`  I got this:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What's the HTTP code you are getting?

Comment: Unfortunately 503.  I added the header to my answer.   This will not be an easy project.  If it were my project, it would need to be worth $Thousands.  I'm sure it can be done.   My rule of thumb is if I can view a page  in my Browser with JavaScript disabled, I can get it with curl. And I have had some projects that took days to crack.  I wish I had more time.   I would love to crack the Cloudflare security.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue here actually *is* TLS fingerprinting then using an HTTP proxy like [`mitmproxy`](https://mitmproxy.org/), [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com) or [NaïveProxy](https://github.com/klzgrad/naiveproxy) *might* be a possible workaround. For details see disscussion [here](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/4575) and [here](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/tls-fingerprinting-node-js/). Another option could be to use [`curl-impersonate`](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate) as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529199/where-does-cloudflare-detect-web-and-terminal-requests-on-equal-terms#comment126447044_71535508).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with redirect 301.
I just added and problem solved.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```